# Post image to wall without posting to an album

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When using the Facebook site I can upload an image to a **friend's** wall feed without having to add the image to an album first.

I'd like to do the same thing using the Graph API. Is this possible?

If it isn't, I'm curious as to how other people work around this limitation - do you create an album on the the user's friends profile first? Is that even possible? Or do you upload to the user's own album first? In that case will the friend's wall be able to link to it?

Regards,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible for an uploaded image not to be placed in a user's album.  When uploading an image to a user's wall, that image data is stored in a user's album specific for the application.  As with any other albums, there's a 200 (or so) max limit on how many images can be placed there.

The only way for it not to be placed in a user's album is to use a URL to where the image is hosted.

Answer (score 2):

This posts a link to the image the url provided, meaning the image has to stay hosted. Also, the image is not full size as if you had uploaded it. It's a small preview image

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to post a request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<uid>/feed?message=xyz&picture=url_to_pic
```

This will create a message on the user's wall with the image included. It will not create or attach this image to an album.

Comment: Hi. For that I need a URL. I wish to upload a local image.3

Comment: Hi. To do that I'd need a URL. Instead, I wis to upload a local image.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work that way. The image has to be accessible via a url.